# Compare two tables in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I'm making a website to show various statistics regarding games.

I got two seperate tables in an sql-database. One called PlayerMatch and another called Match.

The two columns I want to compare is TeamId in PlayerMatch (PlayerMatch.TeamId vs. WinningTeamId in Match (Match.WinningTeamId)

To show it all, I have made a table, where I have placed some asp:repeaters inside.
Here is one of them, as they are all essentially the same.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repHighGPM" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <td><a href="Match.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Match.MatchNumber") %>"><%#Eval("Match.MatchNumber") %></a></td>
          <td><%#Eval("Match.WinningTeamId") %></td>
          <td><%#Eval("Name") %></td>
          <td>
               <img src=' <%#Eval("Image") %>' /></td>
          <td><%#Eval("GoldPerMinute") %></td>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now, the problem is that as it is now it will only show the Id of the team who won (Match.WinningTeamId). But not if the player was on that team. So essentially it just needs to check if PlayerMatch.TeamId == Match.WinningTeamId. And if that is true it should write "won match", while false will be "lost match"

Any ideas? I know it should be some kind of if-else function, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You better do it in your SQL query

Answer (score 0):

You could use the inner join in sql query :
make a datasource to your databse write the query after that add the datasource to repeater DataSourceID="" ....

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repHighGPM" runat="server" DataSourceID="match">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <td><a href="Match.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Match.MatchNumber") %>"><%#Eval("Match.MatchNumber") %></a></td>
          <td><%#Eval("Match.WinningTeamId") %></td>
          <td><%#Eval("Name") %></td>
          <td>
               <img src=' <%#Eval("Image") %>' /></td>
          <td><%#Eval("GoldPerMinute") %></td>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>    



    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="match" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:database %>" SelectCommand="select m.match number, m.winningTeamID, Name ,Image from Match m inner join
        playermatch p on p.Teamid = m.WinningTeamId"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

for more information about inner join read this article :
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the following solution:

```
    public string MatchResult (object Result) {
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    DOTA2DataContext db = new DOTA2DataContext();
    var Victory = Result;
    var TeamId = db.PlayerMatches.Where(x => x.TeamId == id);
    var WinningTeam = db.Matches.Where(x => x.WinningTeamId == id);
    {
        if (TeamId == WinningTeam)
        { 
            return "Won match";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Lost match";
        }

    }
}
```

And the repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repHighD" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <td><a href="Match.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Match.MatchNumber") %>"><%#Eval("Match.MatchNumber") %></a></td>
                            <td><%# MatchResult(Eval("Match.WinningTeamId"))%></td>
                            <td><%#Eval("Hero.Name") %></td>
                            <td>
                                <img src=' <%#Eval("Hero.Image") %>' /></td>
                            <td><%#Eval("Denies") %></td>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```